# Periodontal grade bleach for dental rinse?

Tags: bleach, diluting, periodontitis

Consensus has emerged in recent years about the benefits of a dental
rinse made of diluted bleach (Annex of links below).  Everything that
I found online says that bleach is caustic to plastics.  Household
bleach comes in plastic containers, so there is be chemical
interaction with the plastic, even if the container structure is not
compromised.

**Is there a purer grade of bleach for periodontal purposes?**  If it is periodontal grade, I would then expect the container to be suitable for the basicity.

---

**ANNEX: CONSENSUS ON ADVISABILITY OF DILUTED BLEACH RINSE LEANING TOWARD 0.25%**

0.06% sodium hypochlorite :
6% x (1oz/6tsp) / 16oz = 0.0625%
[DILUTED BLEACH SOLUTION DIRECTIONS](https://www.periomem.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Bleach-Instructions-April-2019.pdf)

0.05% to 0.25% :
[Mouth rinsing With Bleach: A Promising Alternative To Chlorhexidine?](https://www.speareducation.com/spear-review/2017/10/mouthrinsing-with-bleach-a-promising-alternative-to-chlorhexidine)

0.25% :
[Sodium hypochlorite (dilute chlorine bleach) oral rinse in patient self-care](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26856131)

0.25% :
[SAFELY Use DILUTED BLEACH As MOUTHWASH! - Diluted Bleach Mouthwash Recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNO4wtfnjo)

Overall Google search :
[dental-rinse bleach](https://www.google.com/search?q=dental-rinse+bleach)

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here, one of which is barely medical and the others are not at all. All your questions about chlorine's interaction with plastic belong on Chemistry.SE. The final sentence in your question is the only one I see that's on topic here. Can you please edit the question to focus on one question that's medically relevant?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've significantly revised the question.

Comment: The question is still about packaging and chemistry. I think you need to take the whole question to Chemistry.SE.

Comment: I'm not asking about the chemistry.  I'm asking periodontists whether they know of periodontal grade bleach solution.  If there is, it would be known by periodontists.  In general, it would not be known by chemists.

Comment: `within a container that is impervious to bleach?` -- That is asking about the chemistry and packaging.

Comment: I feel it is not a general chemistry question because a periodontist might know of such a solution available, but he or she does not need to know about the chemistry. Chemistry is a broad topic, but this is a very specific question whose answer would be more in the awareness of periodontists (if there is an answer, that is). I further modified the question to clarify that I'm not asking anyone to figure out the material composition of a container. If there is a periodontal grade bleach solution, it will come in a suitable container.

Comment: @user2153235 I may agree with you, but unfortunately there's not many active users on this site, and no periodontists as far as I know. Chem.SE has far more users, and your question probably has a higher chance of getting answered there. Perhaps check the "Periodic Table" chat room to see if they would welcome a migration of this question, before you cross-post it.

Comment: Interesting -- one of the pre-existing tags is periodontitis. I couldn't find a periodic table chat on the chemistry SE, but found one for a subject agnostic SE [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table): "11:29 Is chemistry.stackexchange.com the right place for a question about periodontal grade bleach rinse? I'm interested more in the prospect that such a solution would come in a container made of suitable material, and less in the chemistry details.  [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) is the motivation for me asking in this chat."

Comment: @user2153235 Thank you, the question is okay now.